# Eliminate non-existant/null values from a csv dataset with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, python-2.x

I have the following script used to validate a csv file I have before it can be rendered on a d3.js visualization I'm creating:

```
import csv

num_headers = 9

def url_escaper(data):
  for line in data:
    yield line.replace('&','&amp;')

with open("adzuna_input.csv", 'r') as file_in, open("adzuna_output.csv", 'w') as file_out:
    csv_in = csv.reader(url_escaper(file_in))
    csv_out = csv.writer(file_out)
    for i, row in enumerate(csv_in):

        if len(row) == num_headers:
            csv_out.writerow(row)
        else:
            print "line %d is malformed" % i
```

as you can see, I eliminate the character `&` replacing it with the escaped `&amp;`, I tried to do something like this for whitespace or null values but it wasn't very effective.

I think it would be better to determine if any of the column values are wholly made up of whitespace or are totally null and then just forsake that index for the data as malformed as I do with ones that are too long or too short.

I'm stuck on the logic of how to execute this requirement, would it be something like

```
for i, row in enumerate(csv_in):
    if i is null || whitespace:
        print "line %d is malformed" % i
```

---

**ADDITION**

I tried like this:

```
for i, row in enumerate(csv_in, starts):

    if row.strip() & len(row) == num_headers:
        csv_out.writerow(row)
    else:
        print "line %d is malformed" % i
```

but it says `"AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'"`

My input data looks like this

```
http://www.edsa-project.eu/adzuna/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzIjoia0EtLWlpVHhUMUNtSFM0SzE4TUVzUSIsImkiOiIzMzI2OTEyMjIifQ.qK3xtYQDxRpKJkNargPu6Jef4njm2fSZnNIVulRHoqA,Software Development Manager,Spring Technology ,Woolstone,52.042198,&,&,&,1
http://www.edsa-project.eu/adzuna/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzIjoia0EtLWlpVHhUMUNtSFM0SzE4TUVzUSIsImkiOiIzMzI4NDM1MzgifQ.pYnBX-APPdB3edTRC_M8x6usmBq_GfIxcdZOXSLJN04,Data Scientists Python R Scala Java or Matlab,Aspire Data Recruitment,    ,,,United Kingdom,data science|java|python|scala|matlab|analysis,1
```

^the above testing file contains errors in the second example- the second record should be rejected because of the blank lines

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`strip`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) to check if any element in list is empty:

```
for i, row in enumerate(csv_in, start=1):
    if not [e for e in row if not e.strip()]:
        if len(row) == num_headers:
            csv_out.writerow(row)
    else:
        print "line %d is malformed" % i
```

`strip()` will be `True` if element is not empty. So making `if not e.strip()` will give as negation of `False` which is `True` and we'll print out `"line %d is malformed" % i`

> string.strip(s[, chars])
>
> Return a copy of the string with leading and trailing characters
>   removed. If chars is omitted or None, whitespace characters are
>   removed. If given and not None, chars must be a string; the characters
>   in the string will be stripped from the both ends of
>   the string this method is called on.

Example file, second line is empty and the line next to it consists from white spaces only:

```
test


test
```

Output:

```
line 2 is malformed
line 3 is malformed
```

Note that [**`enumerate`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) starts from `0` by default. So i would specify `start=1` parameter to get proper line number.

Comment: what if the line isn't strings? what if it's ints or something- that's possible, strip will still work?

Comment: I don't really understand what `if not row.strip():` is doing

Comment: when you read lines in you file they are strings, and ints inside will be a part of a string

Comment: so then I could add that code as another if condition like a cascade, right after `if len(row) == num_headers:`?

Comment: i would do it like if row.strip(): do something else: print "line %d is malformed" % i

Comment: can I do `if row.strip() && len(row) == num_headers: do something`*next line (and INDENTATION(stupid python))* `else: print "line %d is malformed" % i `?

Comment: do you mean `starts=1`

Comment: ah- ok cool. though I'm having trouble logically fitting that snippet into the structure of the above code- like how to configure it within the scope of the header number validation

Comment: so you are verifying headers only once, right? so the first row would be the header row, check it first, for all other lines check for empty strings and if they are not empty do something

Comment: no no- because some lines have extra `,` in them- and that messes everything else up- I need to get rid of them

Comment: I added the data I'm working with- it seems if the line has the valid number of delimiters, but the values within the delimiters are empyty it won't eliminate the line- but that's what I'm looking to do- if what is inside `,` and another `,` is whitespace, null, empty- something like that- then I need to throw out that record